# Webpack image loader with dynamic inline background images via CSS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack with react, and I usually import and use my images as such:

```
 import CalNotices from 'assets/img/calendar-notices.png';

 <img className='img-center' role='presentation' src={CalNotices}/>
```

that works fine, and when I do production build, those images area neatly put into appropriate folders.

However, at times, I want to use images for backgrounds, and use it as such:

```
const divStyle = {
     backgroundImage: `url(${item.logo})`,
     backgroundSize: 'contain',
     backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
     backgroundPosition: 'center' 
}
<div className='image-holder' style={divStyle}></div>
```

with item.logo being an absolute path to the image.

This works fine in dev, but when I do a prod build, those images are obviously missing, since they didn't get picked up by the webpack image loader. How should I approach this?

my image loader config is

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
    include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appNodeModules],
    loader: 'file',
    query: {
      name: 'static/media/[name].[ext]'
    }
},
```

Comment: how is `item` defined?

Comment: by that comment I mean, it all works just the same.  You could set your divStyle to `backgroundImage: 'url(${CalNotices})'` and that works just fine and gets bundled like normal.  Somethning is different about the way you populate `item.logo` that might be bypassing webpack.

Comment: @Brandon item is an object containing property logo which holds to absolute path to the background image. that image is never imported via import 'path to image" declaration because it can be any path.

Comment: if you do not import it via webpack then how can webpack bundle it?  Webpack bundles assets by following import statements.

Comment: but then how can I import it if I don't know the path of it and it can be anything? the src comes from dynamic json

Comment: it sounds like you need to retrieve the images dynamically at run time.  If these dynamic urls are absolute it should just be working.  if the paths are relative, then you don't know what they are relative to so how could you load them anyway?

Comment: yea i hear you. It should be working but images are stored in src/assets/img/logos. I use modules: [ path.resolve('./src'),] in webpack config, so i can refer to them as import CalNotices from 'assets/img/calendar-notices.png';  That works when webpack is loading the images, but if I load them directly from my app (as I do here), i need to use absolute path such as '/src/assets/img/logos/credit-xxx-logo.jpg' , which screws everything up

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments (all of the images are in `/src/assets/img/logos`), you can leverage webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#require-context) functionality to bundle the entire logo folder at build time:

```
// causes webpack to find and bundle *all* files in logos or one of its subfolders.
const logoContext = require.context("assets/img/logos", true, /\.(png|jpg)$/);

// later...in your render() method
// assumes item.logo is a path relative to the logos folder
// example: "credit-card-xxx.jpg" or "./credit-card-xxx.jpg"
const logoUrl = logoContext.resolve(item.logo);
```

Comment: I've not tried webpack 2, but the [migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) doesn't specifically call this out as changed so it *probably* works.